# React Private Routing through id

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

So I'm using `PrivateRoute` in React to serve some components. Everything's been working fine until I specified the exact path like below:

```
<PrivateRoute exact path="/info/:id" render={(props) => <BookInfo {...props} />} />
```

The above path works fine if I serve it normally using `Route` but routing though `PrivateRoute` gives me the following error.
[image]

**PrivateRoute.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, auth, ...rest}) => (
    <Route {...rest} render={ props => 
        auth.isAuthenticated === true ?
        (<Component {...props}/>) : (<Redirect to ='/login'/>)}/>
)

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    auth: state.auth
})

export default connect (mapStateToProps)(PrivateRoute);
```

I don't know what's causing this, some help is much appreciated.

Comment: `PrivateRoute` needs a `component` prop ro be passed. You are missing that prop while calling `<PrivateRoute exact path="/info/:id" render={(props) => <BookInfo {...props} />} />`

Comment: How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Try this `<PrivateRoute exact path="/info/:id" component={BookInfo} />`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Issue

Your `PrivateRoute` component is expecting a `component` prop to be passed, it doesn't handle the other props a `Route` component handles.

```
const PrivateRoute = ({
  component: Component, // <-- only handles component prop
  auth, ...rest
}) => (
  <Route {...rest} render={ props => 
    auth.isAuthenticated === true ?
    (<Component {...props}/>) : (<Redirect to ='/login'/>)}/>
)
```

## Solution

Pass your `BookInfo` on the `component` prop so it is piped through.

```
<PrivateRoute exact path="/info/:id" component={BookInfo} />
```

Refactor your `PrivateRoute` component to render either a `Route` with all the props passed to it, or the `Redirect` component.

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ auth, ...props }) => auth.isAuthenticated ? (
    <Route {...props} />
  ) : (
    <Redirect to ='/login'/>
  );
```